# Implement Message Access Profile (Sink side) on Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, bluetooth, profile

I'm intent to making Android support Message Access Profile (on Sink side) that can get incoming message from iPhone via bluetooth, same with [Smart Watch do](http://www.razorianfly.com/2012/12/07/pebble-officially-announces-sms-and-imessage-support-for-iphone-video/)

But i don't know how to implement it on Android.

Comment: Can you let us know the steps you have taken so far

Comment: I just find out this topic: http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2011/04/obex-message-access-profile.html
And a SDK can implement it but i neet more information: http://www.mecel.se/products/bluetooth/mecel-betula-sdk/mecel-betula-sdk-android-version

I need a produce to build it, but no information.

Answer (score 2):

MAP ([Message Access Profile](http://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/MAP.aspx)) uses the [OBEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange) ([Object Exchange](http://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/OBEX.aspx)) profile to talk over. So begin with understand ([read the specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=230888)) and implement OBEX. A good thing to build is a OBEX package parser/builder. The are more profiles that using OBEX as a base, example OPP ([Object Push Profile](http://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/OPP.aspx)) and PBAP ([Phonebook Book Access Profile](http://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/PBAP.aspx)).

When you hava a parser/builder you implement MAP on it. MAP ([specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=215400)) have two parts MAS (Message Access service) and MNS (Message Notification service). Depending of what you want to do you may need to impelment both. As you say in the question that you want to recive notifications from the phone about new message and the get it, then you need both parts. If you only want to read message from the phone then you only need to implement the MAS part.