# How to implement bluetooth profile MAP(Message Access Profile) on Android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, sms

How to implement bluetooth profile MAP(Message Access Profile) on Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

A moment ago I wrote a short overview about what you need to do for implement MAP (Message Access Profile) here at Stackoverflow. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377247/implement-message-accesss-profile-sink-side-on-android/17404303#17404303). I hope it was a similar answer to what you was looking for.