# Application about bluetooth message access profile(MAP) under android platform

Tags: android, dictionary, bluetooth

Recently, I have an application which is related to Bluetooth MAP.

I know that MAP(message access profile) is already supported from Android 4.4 (kitkat). But I did really can not get more information about this from Android official site including the API introduce

What I can search is only one head file about this bt_mce.h in the link below : https://source.android.com/devices/halref/bt__mce_8h_source.html

And there is only one callback function declaration in it, no definition, no description, and no use case, sample source code for it.

I also can not find any description in Android API list about bluetooth MAP, nothing.

No API definition about this function in API level 22 at all:
*developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html*

My questions are:
1. Where can I find the reference document from Android official to support my application, at least I need know which interfaces can be used to support MAP function under Android platform, I just want to implement a simple App to verify my idea with my android mobile phone(OS 5.0.1). Google just said it is supported from Android 4.4.

2.Because I can not get some more support information about this, it is really not a popular application in the market. So I am not sure some questions, like:
As a MCE device in this application, is it necessary to implement something in MSE device side? or some other setting in MSE device side?

Or just only use my target MCE device with my application(of course, both of MCE and MSE should support MAP) to connect with MSE device? and the finish the user case as the specification definition?

Thank you very much, appreciate any useful information from you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the MAP Specification as pdf from the
   [bluetooth org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377247/implement-message-accesss-profile-sink-side-on-android/17404303#17404303). Google said MAP was supported from Android 4.4 on, however on my phone the first time it was available was with Lollipop 5.0 and still today the mail functionality of the profile is missing.
2. MAP is nomally used in cars, to display SMS and mail on the car screen, where the Message Server Equipment (MSE) is the phone delivering the messages and the handsfree unit in the car receives the messages (Message Client Equipment, MCE). There is a very nice introduction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377247/implement-message-accesss-profile-sink-side-on-android/17404303#17404303) on stackoverflow for what it needs to implement MAP.